# Is this a valid proof for DeMorgan's law using double set inclusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am quite new to set theory, and I have tried proving the following set theory question. So, I was wondering if my proof is considered to be valid.

Here is the question:
Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $U$. Using double set inclusion, prove that $$(A\cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$$

My proof:

Let $x \in (A \cap B)^c$ 

 $\Leftrightarrow$
$x \notin (A \cap B)$ by definition of set complement

 $\Leftrightarrow$
$\neg (x \in A \text{ and } x \in B))$ 

 $\Leftrightarrow$ $x \notin A \text{ or } x \notin B)$ by Demorgan's Law

 $\Leftrightarrow$
$x \in A^c \cup B^c$ by definition of set union

Therefore, I have shown that $(A\cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$, as was required.
▯

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: You could put in an extra line just before the last one: $x\in A^c$ or $x\in B^c$ (by definition of set complement).  And give a reason (definition of set intersection) for the line with no reason.  And if this is for a class, then when they say that they want double set inclusion, they may expect you to write it out twice with $\Rightarrow$ instead of $\Leftrightarrow$, once in the direction that you have it, and once in the reverse direction.  But really, you've got it.

Comment: @TobyBartels Got it, thanks. I just wanted to clarify - wouldn't the double implication sign actually cover both set inclusions? Thus, it's equivalent to showing both $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftarrow$? I just had this question for a test, and I wrote up the proof with the double implication sign, so I'm quite afraid I may lose marks as a result..

Comment: Yes, it's equivalent.  The only issue is if the grader expects a very particular form and the instructions are supposed to tell you this.  What you wrote here is certainly acceptable in any normal context; I'm just trying to imagine what could possibly go wrong.  If there was never any warning about this in class (like what @Abhishek Vangipuram apparently got from their professor), then you should be fine.

Comment: @TobyBartels Yes, it was never stated in class. I have also done the same in a written assignment that I had to hand in, but that wasn’t an issue, and everything was fine. The only concern I have is that in this question, it was stated that we have to use the double set inclusion technique. But logically, what I wrote here is equivalent to proving the double set inclusion. It’s just a different way to show, which I just wanted to verify is true.